# How do i change the color of a slider track track in Javafx using css?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a music player and i am trying to change the slider track color and not just the border color when i do

-fx-background-color: it changes the border background color
-fx-color: changes the slider dot

i tried 
-fx-track-fill: it doesnt work.

this is what i have:

```
.root
{
    -fx-background-color: #383838;
}
.vbox
{
    -fx-background-color: #549534;
}
.button
{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#dc9656,#ab4642);
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;

}
.label
{
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}
.slider
{
     -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#dc9656,#ab4642);
     -fx-color:#549534;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Solution*

The color of the inside of the slider is controlled by the JavaFX CSS [looked up color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor):

```
-fx-control-inner-background
```

[image: colored slider]

You can change the color in code:

```
slider.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: palegreen;");
```

Or in CSS:

```
.slider .track {
    -fx-control-inner-background: palegreen;
}
```

*Background*

Here is the standard CSS for the slider control (from `modena.css` inside the `jfxrt.jar` file in the Java 8 installation):

```
.slider .track {
      -fx-background-color:
          -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
          linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
          linear-gradient(to bottom,
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, 0%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -5%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -12%)
          );
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0.25em, 0.25em, 0.166667em; /* 3 3 2 */
    -fx-padding: 0.25em; /* 3 */
}
```

As you can see the slider track has a layered background with a shadow highlight, a border and an inner shading.  The inner shading is a gradient derived from the `fx-control-inner-background`.  This is why changing the value of that looked up color will change the color of the inside of the track.  If you are unfamiliar with the layering concept for backgrounds in JavaFX CSS, then read the [JavaFX Region CSS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).