# JavaFx CSS - Slider Track

Tags: css, javafx, slider

Trying to style Slider using CSS. In IntelliJ ide I notice the line is underlined & gives an error (as shown below).

I referred to [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226831/3127144) [Link2](https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/do-you-really-understand-css-linear-gradients-631d9a895caf) [Link3](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470) get some understanding of Linear Gradient, but still unable to understand what is causing the error.

Hope issue faced is clear, await inputs.

**Error:**

```
Mismatched parameters ([[from <point> to <point> | to <side-or-corner>] ,]? 
[[repeat | reflect] ,]? <color-stop> [, <color-stop>]+) less... (Ctrl+F1) 

Inspection info: This inspection detects unknown functions and illegal function parameters.
```

**IDE:**

[image: Code:]

Comment: When you run the application does JavaFX report any parsing errors? If not, this may be an issue with Intelllij not recognizing JavaFX specific CSS.

Comment: Also be aware that not all of the CSS functionality is included with JavaFx, some things just wont work. Not sure if this is one of them, just putting it out there. Please refer to [this reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepaint) to help with determining if you are doing it correctly.

Comment: @Slaw there is no parsing error when the application is run. Just that the error makes me doubt if am doing something wrong.
Hypnic Jerk - Thanks for that info.

Added:
The error is showing because of - derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%) If I replace this with just -fx-text-box-border or say any other color it does not give error. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: When I search "CSS derive` in Google many of the results deal with JavaFX specifically. It might be that `derive` is JavaFX-specific (but I'm unfamiliar with non-JavaFX CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51344773/3127144) where instead of using the derive the code is specified as:

```
linear-gradient(to right, #2D819D 20%, #969696 20%);
```

I have adopted the above approach & this eliminates the error. Hope this is the right approach

Comment: I just want to point out that what you had before is valid JavaFX CSS. The problem is that _Intellij doesn't recognize it_ as valid CSS likely because it's not aware of JavaFX-specific CSS features.